# Error: [$injector:modulerr] in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack

I am trying to create an application using MEAN stack. my controller code looks like this.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    console.log("Hello World from console");
}])();
```

My index.html looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <title>
        Contact List App</title>
    </head>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script scr = "controllers/controller.js"></script>

    <body ng-app = "myApp">
        <div class = "container" ng-controller = "AppCtrl">
            <h1>Contact List App</h1>

            <table class= "table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Number</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

It throws Error: [$injector:modulerr] Please help me if anyone has faced this problem.

Comment: Is it `<script scr`? or `<script src`?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak Thanks ! That was just a silly mistake I couldnt find out !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the invocation operator () off the end of controller.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was I typed scr instead of src in script tag . Lame mistake from my side

Answer (score 0):

Try to inject $scope and $http in your angular module.